# Assigning colors to segmented pictures in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, k-means, image-segmentation

I was dealing with color segmentation with MATLAB. I used k-means clustering based on [this](http://www.ijest.info/docs/IJEST10-02-10-117.pdf) document and come this far codewise;

```
global imgRGB;
global imgLAB;
img = imgRGB;

cform = makecform('srgb2lab');
imgLAB = applycform(img, cform);
ab = double(imgLAB(:,:,2:3));
rows = size(ab,1)
cols = size(ab,2);
ab = reshape(ab, rows*cols, 2);
cluster = 5;
[idx center] = kmeans(ab, cluster, 'distance', 'sqEuclidean', 'Replicates', 5);
label = reshape(idx, rows, cols);
figure; imshow(label, []);
imgSeg = cell(5);
rgb_label = repmat(pixel_labels, [1 1 3]);
for k=1:cluster
    color = img;
    color(rgb_label ~= k) = 0;
    imgSeg{k} = color;
end
figure; 
imshow(imgSeg{1});
```

I take image as input that is why it is defined global.

For a colored image like the one in link, it produces the grayscale output.

[image]

I think it assigns gray tones as colors but I need to assign a color to each cluster. I mean not gray tone but a color. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a different [`colormap`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) for your figure, when displaying the labels directly.

Try:

```
figure; 
imshow(label, []);
colormap( rnad(max(imgSeg{1}(:))+1, 3) ); % use random color map
```

However, if you wish to convert the `pixel_labels` to an RGB image (3 color channels per pixel), you want to use [`ind2rgb`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2rgb.html) (instead of replicating the labels to all channels). Replace `rgb_label = repmat(pixel_labels, [1 1 3]);` with

```
rgb_label = ind2rgb(pixel_labels, rand(max(pixel_labels(:)),3));
```

Comment: I am sorry that didn't work. Should I use colormap function elsewhere in code?

Comment: Nope, still not working. I wonder if it is because of this line;

`rgb_label = repmat(pixel_labels, [1 1 3]);`